Can't turn bluetooth on Ubuntu 22.04.04, using a Beelink Mini S, 12 pro generation
My Mini came with Windows 11. I booted from a USB and tried Ubuntu. Wifi did not work, but bluetooth did. I then went to Windows 11 and connected my bluetooth device. It worked well also.
Then I installed Ubuntu alongside Windows 11. The wifi worked, but that is when the bluetooth problem started. I was not able to turn on bluetooth. It would not let me toggle the switch. I went back to the USB boot for Ubuntu, and this time I full installed Ubuntu 22.04. To my dismay, I can toggle the switch, but it will not turn on, even if it lets me toggle it. It does not change color and nothing happens related to bluetooth.
This is the error I get when I try:
Mini-S: ~$ sudo hciconfig
hci0:   Type: Primary  Bus: USB
    BD Address: 00:00:00:00:00:00  ACL MTU: 0:0  SCO MTU: 0:0
    DOWN 
    RX bytes:210 acl:0 sco:0 events:5 errors:0
    TX bytes:20 acl:0 sco:0 commands:5 errors:0

I tried the following and got this:
MINI-S:~$ hciconfig hci0 up
Can't init device hci0: Operation not permitted (1)

My bluetooth is still not working.
Here is more information:
MINI-S:~$ lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net; 00:14.3 
Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:54f0] DeviceName: Onboard - Ethernet 
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0244] 
Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi 
Kernel modules: iwlwifi 
-- 
01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller 
[10ec:8168] (rev 15) 
     Subsystem: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:0123] 
     Kernel driver in use: r8169 
     Kernel modules: r8169 – 

MINI-S:~$ uname -r; lsusb; sudo dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm' 
6.5.0-44-generic 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 093a:2510 Pixart Imaging, Inc. Optical Mouse 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 328f:0073 EMEET HD Webcam eMeet C950 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 8087:0026 Intel Corp. AX201 Bluetooth 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 05ac:0267 Apple, Inc. Magic Keyboard A1644 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub – 

0.386510] ACPI: thermal: [Firmware Bug]: No valid trip found 
[ 3.456189] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version 83.e8f84e98.0 so-a0-hr-b0-83.ucode op_mode iwlmvm 
[ 3.929346] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] Finished loading DMC firmware i915/adlp_dmc.bin (v2.20) 
[ 3.953128] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] GT0: GuC firmware i915/tgl_guc_70.bin version 70.5.1 
[ 3.953135] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] GT0: HuC firmware i915/tgl_huc.bin version 7.9.3 
[ 4.659966] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22 
[ 4.660559] NET: Registered PF_BLUETOOTH protocol family – 
[ 4.660562] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized 
[ 4.660597] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized 
[ 4.660600] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized 
[ 4.660604] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized 
[ 4.692009] Bluetooth: hci0: Device revision is 2 
[ 4.692024] Bluetooth: hci0: Secure boot is enabled 
[ 4.692026] Bluetooth: hci0: OTP lock is enabled 
[ 4.692026] Bluetooth: hci0: API lock is enabled 
[ 4.692027] Bluetooth: hci0: Debug lock is disabled 
[ 4.692028] Bluetooth: hci0: Minimum firmware build 1 week 10 2014 – 
[ 4.692029] Bluetooth: hci0: Bootloader timestamp 2019.40 buildtype 1 build 38 
[ 4.692753] Bluetooth: hci0: Failed to load Intel firmware file intel/ibt-0040-1050.sfi (-2) 
[ 4.693467] Bluetooth: hci0: Reading supported features failed (-56) 
[ 4.693471] Bluetooth: hci0: Error reading debug features 
[ 4.694933] Bluetooth: hci0: Failed to read MSFT supported features (-56) 
[ 4.772188] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3 
[ 4.772193] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast 
[ 4.772197] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized – 


Please edit the question to include results from terminal for lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net; uname -r; lsusb; sudo dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'

The problem is that the firmware isn't found. To fix it, go to terminal and run:
cd /lib/firmware/intel
sudo wget https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/plain/intel/ibt-0040-1050.sfi
sudo wget https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/plain/intel/ibt-0040-1050.ddc

Then reboot.

Please add a space between wget and https on the second sudo wget command. This solved my problem. Thank you, Jeremy31!

Could someone add the tags Beelink and Mini-S to this?  It will help a lot of people that have the Mini-S solve their problem.

I think Beelink Mini-S people will find it if they search correctly
